# Populate backgrid with Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, backgrid

Hello I'm using backgrid. I am trying to have a head and the left most column with some data and all the other to be filled by checkboxes like this
[view](http://screencast.com/t/mpiz8WHAM). I can't figure out how to do it so does anybody know how to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These `backgrid` guys have a package known as `backgrid-grouped-column`. You can use that [FortesSolutions/backgrid-grouped-columns](https://github.com/FortesSolutions/backgrid-grouped-columns) . But it's just a mere proof of concept

Comment: oh I didn't know about this one. Thanks for the help

Comment: there is another question. I would be glad if you could answer that [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35356476/heatmap-leaflet-in-a-hidden-div)

Comment: sure. just let me check if I know the answer